# Reduce output time - count with groupby (python, pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a loop that calculates the "total_count" of a group of elements from multiple periods. Is there a way to optimize the script to have a shorter output time? The dataframe is 33MD and running a loop takes over 300++ms. Actual script runs over 50k loops; which takes over 2 days to complete.

```
#sample df with similar output time
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(400000,1)), columns=['type'])
df['class'] = np.random.randint(1, 7, df.shape[0])
df['country'] = np.random.randint(1, 12, df.shape[0])
df['period'] = np.random.randint(2010, 2018, df.shape[0])
df['season'] = np.random.randint(1, 4, df.shape[0])
```

```
%%time
#period
tr1_sta = 2011
tr1_end = 2016

h0 = 'type'
h1 = 'class'
h2 = 'country'

holder = [h0,h1,h2]

df = (df.set_index(holder).assign(tr1_tc = df[(df['period'].between(tr1_sta, tr1_end))].groupby(holder)['season'].count()).reset_index())
```

Kindly advise 
Thank you

Comment: Please can you provide sample data as plain text and the expected output?

Comment: @Corralien, thank you for the reply. I've added a sample data with a size that gives about 300++ms Wall time from my machine. Expected output is the same output from my original script, I am hoping to find possible ways to reduce output time, hence, no changes to the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code took 75.1ms on my computer. The code below run in 14.6ms:

```
df['tr1_tc'] = (df.assign(tr1_tc=df['period'].between(tr1_sta, tr1_end))
                  .groupby(holder)['tr1_tc'].transform('sum'))
print(df)

# Output
        type  class  country  period  season  tr1_tc
0          1      5        1    2016       2    1343
1          1      5        9    2014       1    1302
2          2      3        4    2013       2    1299
3          0      6        1    2014       1    1326
4          2      4        5    2012       3    1367
...      ...    ...      ...     ...     ...     ...
349995     2      1        3    2010       3    1332
349996     0      1        8    2015       1    1362
349997     1      3        1    2013       3    1283
349998     1      6        7    2015       3    1305
349999     0      6        9    2017       2    1250

[350000 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: i'm having trouble getting the numbers to match in the actual data. However, it works perfectly for the sample data, hence, will mark this as answer. Will post another question if i can't work it through. Thank you.